# What does "< >" mean in Dart?

Tags: dart, flutter

Through an online Dart course, I've found some values bracketed with "less than" and "greater than" marks such as ["List< E >"](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/List-class.html).

e.g.

```
List<int> fixedLengthList = new List(5);
```

I couldn't find a direct answer online, probably because that question was too basic. Could someone explain what those marks exactly indicate? Or any links if possible.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This are generic type parameters. It allows specializations of classes.

`List` is a list that can contain any value (if no type parameter is passed `dynamic` is used by default).
`List<int> is a list that only allows integer values and`null`.

You can add such Type parameters to your custom classes as well.
Usually single upper-case letters are used for type parameter names like `T`, `U`, `K` but they can be other names like `TKey` ...

```
class MyClass<T> {
  T value;
  MyClass(this.value);
}

main() {
  var mcInt = MyClass<int>(5);
  var mcString = MyClass<String>('foo');
  var mcStringError = MyClass<String>(5); // causes error because `5` is an invalid value when `T` is `String`
}
```

See also https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#generics

Comment: The keyword "generic" is totally what I missed! Thanks for your prompt answer with an example. I will need more time to understand those parameters as I've just started to learn Dart. Anyway your answer has helped me a lot already :-)

Answer (score 2):

for example If you intend for a list to **contain only strings**, you can declare it as `List<String>` (read that as “list of string”)