# How to get Android Studio quick fix menu to add return type Future<void> instead of just Future

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio, types, async-await

## Problem Statement

### Good Behavior

If I define the function `foo` as follows, the quick fix menu in Android Studio will suggest "Add return type" `Future<int>`. I prefer the type parameter symbols (less-than & greater-than symbols) included, so this is fine.

```dart
foo() {
  return Future.value(1);
}
```

[image: quick fix menu showing a return type Future of type int]

### Bad Behavior

But if we define `bar` as follows, the quick fix menu only suggests the return type `Future` rather than `Future<dynamic>` ([which is implied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54426802/what-does-mean-in-dart#answer-54426938)) or `Future<void>`. I want it to suggest `Future<void>` because it [doesn’t produce a usable value](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await#completing-with-a-value).

```dart
bar() {
  return Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
}
```

[image: quick fix menu showing a return type Future without type parameter symbols]

## Question

How can we get the quick fix menu to suggest `Future<void>` instead of the bare `Future`? Is there a linter rule that could also flag bare `Future` return types?